# Enable audit to azure DB

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database

I've created Azure DB and I want to enable audit (e.g. which user change entry,when,etc),
How can I do it ?

I Click on manage and didn't find any place when I can do that...

Comment: Ask yourself how you would accomplish this with SQL Server, as it will likely be a similar technique.

Comment: @DavidMakogon-I go to the administration tab of the DB and didnt find when I can active it...

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify *what* you're trying to activate. From your comment, it sounds like you're trying to use a built-in auditing feature that exists in SQL Server (vs. just general practices for auditing user-level changes). Also: You may want to review the differences between SQL Server and SQL Database, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff394115.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure SQL Database does not currently support Change Data Capture (CDC) which is the feature in standard SQL Server that provides in-built auditing capabilities.  You will need to solve this auditing requirement some other way (pre / post triggers?)

The full set of Azure SQL DB limitations (and differences to standard SQL Server) is listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff394115.aspx.

There's also an older TechNet blog on how to achieve a workable solution here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2976.how-to-enable-sql-azure-change-tracking.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much voted up!,I read about DB triggers 1. where should I put this code?2.Can I do the DB triggers to to all the my DB tables at once or I need to do it for every specific table in my DB...

Comment: John, check out this great post from John Galloway on how to achieve what you need to do (short answer is you need to put triggers on any table you care about changes to). http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/adding-simple-trigger-based-auditing-to-your-sql-server-database